# Disponibilização de webservice oculto

Tags: visual-studio, url, navegador-de-internet

Estou com uma dúvida e preciso da ajuda de vocês.
Eu tenho alguns webservices que precisam por solicitação do cliente que não seja acessados por browser porém possam ser acessados por url caso digitem todo o caminho mais os parametros. Ou seja se o usuário tentar visualizar a tela do webservice o usuário verá uma página de erro personalizada, mas se o usuário digitar todo o url com os parametros corretos e etc , o mesmo recebe a resposta normalmente.

O que acontece é que dessa forma eu preciso toda vez que um novo cliente desse meu cliente precisa referenciar o webservice na aplicação eu preciso desfazer esse bloqueio e e permitir que o visual studio enxergue pelo seu browser interno o webservice para adicionar a referencia dentro do projeto e depois disso o bloquear novamente.

Minha pergunta: Existe alguma forma de se referenciar o webservice sem que o visual studio enxergue o mesmo no seu processo de adição da referencia de forma que eu não precise desbloquear o mesmo e assim os webmethods sejam visualizados pelo browser internos do visual studio no momento da referenciação??

Comment: Existem melhores maneiras de proteger seu webservice e fazer essas manobras todas. De uma lida sobre tokenização e CORS, deve resolver melhor o problema, e ficará mais seguro e menos burocrático.

Comment: Inclusive, se for um serviço na web, você pode usar o [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/api-management/) para terceirizar isso para vc.